# Novel about time traveller amongst a group that go back in time to view historical events

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, novella

I am searching for the name of a short novel, it was a bundle of novel inside one book, it must have been a famous sci fi author

The story is about humans from the future taking pleasure to teleport in groups to an event in the past, like the day before the fall of the city of Rome, and they were always talking between them about the best event in all of human history.

I remember the hero falls in love with a woman from one of the places they were visiting, and how he liked how authentic she was because she was truly living and not a simple passenger of time, he tries to warn her of the imminent threat and what he was doing was of course forbidden by his group/peers/companion.

Comment: "Up the line" by Silverberg? There was a lot of sex in it, but I don't remember the main character falling in love with a woman.

Comment: The famous story ["Vintage Season"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vintage_Season) by Catherine L. Moore and Henry Kuttner fits the description of people traveling from Earth's future to sample the best May weather here, the greatest spectacle there. But in that story, the protagonist is a man of the present who becomes enchanted with a woman from the future.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron intriguingly Silverberg wrote a companion piece to "Vintage Season" called "In Another Country". It was published in a collection of 4 novellas. Maybe this fits with the OP's memory of "a bundle of novels inside one book"?

Comment: The protagonist in Up the Line certainly falls in love with a woman from the time. Byzantium, I think. "Pulcheria. O great, great, multi-great grandmother!" She was described as voluptuous IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be [*Up the Line*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_the_Line) by Robert Silverberg.

> Jud Elliott II is a failed Harvard history masters student in 2059. Bored with his job as a law clerk, he takes up a position with the Time Service as a Time Courier.
>
> After an introductory course, Jud shunts up and down the time line ("up the line" is travel into the past; "down the line" is forward time travel, but only to "now-time," Jud's present of 2059) as a guide for tourists visiting ancient and medieval Byzantium.
>
> Jud's problems include not only stupid tourists, but also greedy and mentally unstable colleagues who attempt to cause various types of havoc with the past. He is forced to break the rules in order to patch things up without drawing the attention of the Time Patrol.
>
> **When he meets and falls in love with the 'marvelous transtemporal paradox called Pulcheria' - his own multi-great grandmother** - Jud succumbs to the lure of the past, **creates irreparable paradoxes, and faces the inescapable clutches of the Time Patrol.**
>
> Silverberg's narrative includes some cleverly worked out details about the problems of time-travel tourism. For example, the number of tourists who over the years wish to witness the crucifixion of Jesus has increased the audience at the event from the likely dozens to hundreds and even tens of thousands.
>
> Time-tour guides re-visiting the same event must also take care not to scan their surroundings too closely, lest they make eye contact with themselves leading another tour party.

Comment: When quoting from a source please indicate what is and isn't a quote with quote markdown and say where the quote comes down and provide the link if applicable. I have done it for you in this case.

Comment: ah yes, it is this one, I had just discovered Silverberg